# Как используя .format() добавить строку сразу в несколько позиций?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, format

Допустим есть строка:

```
s = "{}, {} and {}"
s1 = "one"
```

Можно ли как-то вставить вместо фигурных скобок в строке `s` строку `s1`.

Следующий код у меня не сработал:

```
s.format(s1)
```

Знаю, что можно сделать так: `s.format(s1, s1, s1)`.

Но есть ли способ пофилиграннее?

Comment: не совсем понятно к чему тут метка `numpy` - можете пояснить или убрать её?

Comment: ego_xxx для вас опубликовали два ответа, почему ни один из ответов вы не отметили как правильный?

Answer (score 5):

Для этого обычно используют именованные параметры:

```
s = "{one}, {one} and {one}, another: {two}"
one, two = 1, 2
s.format(one=1, two=2)
>>> '1, 1 and 1, another: 2'
```

Также можно передавать параметры в виде словаря:

```
In [80]: s.format(**{"one":1, "two":2})
Out[80]: '1, 1 and 1, another: 2'
```

Answer (score 5):

как вариант:

```
s = "{0}, {0} and {0}"
s.format(s1)

# 'one, one and one'
```